# Tax implications of lump sum vs monthly payments

Tags: united-states, income-tax

My ex-husband and I owned some secondary property along with my brother- & 
sister-in-law and mother- & father-in-law.

The property was for sale when we divorced, and I was to receive 1/6 of the amount received when sold.

The property didn't sell and was then taken off the market. Now, I am requesting the other parties to buy me out, so I can remove myself from ownership.

What are the tax implications of receiving a lump sum payment as opposed to my ex making monthly payments to me?

Comment: what tax law are you talking about? there are different tax laws in different countries, and even different parts of the same country (like US States or Canadian Provinces)...

Comment: Sorry, in US. The property is on the coast of NC.

Comment: Was this a vacation home or an investment property?

Comment: Yes, a secondary residence, a vacation home.

Comment: is the home worth more than when you all bought it?

Answer (score 1):

**This is a question better asked a tax professional (EA or CPA licensed in NC) and a lawyer.** That said, I'll give you some pointers to discuss with your legal and tax advisers:

- Lump sum distribution of sale proceeds vs monthly distribution of sale proceeds - If the monthly distribution comes from a buyer, then you'd have what is called an "[installment sale](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc705.html)", and there are ways to recognize gain on installment sales over time (cannot report sales at loss as installment sales, so if the sale is at loss - you'll have to recognize the loss at the year of sale regardless of how you get the proceeds).

But you'll have to structure the sale accordingly, so I'd suggest doing it with a very good legal and tax advisers counseling you and guiding you on every step. If its a genuine installment sale, and your lawyer and tax adviser stand behind you - you may be able to recognize some of the gain in the year you receive the money, not in the year of sale, as you would with a lump sum proceeds.

- Monthly payments as alimony - if the monthly payments are in fact [alimony](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc452.html), it will be taxed when received (and deductible by your husband) as ordinary income. Have your lawyer go over the agreement that states what money and how you're getting to verify the classification of the payment. Generally, you wouldn't not want to have this income classified as alimony.

Comment: If she has no profit on this sale isn't the rest moot?

Comment: Of course, tax is only on the gains.